# Windows - Sniff application's file accesses

Tags: windows, path, listener, executable, ini

Is there a way I can listen to an application (executable) and get what files is it accessing? The point is that I'm using an application which uses an INI file and sometimes it generates mulptiple INIs in different paths so I need to know what path/ini is the application accessing. I know the INI's file name I just need to know where to find it...

Comment: dir C:\foo.ini /s ? For all other scenarios you need Process Monitor with a path filter

Comment: @Marged I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for an already existing ini file you can find it using Windows file search or in its simplest form from the commandline with `dir C:\foo.ini /s`.

For more complicated scenarios you will want to use `Process Monitor` from sysinternals.
The optimal filter will look something like this:
[image]

(Please note the two green lines, this will filter for all accesses by `bar.exe` to any file with name `foo.ini`)

Results will be shown like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation, It was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) from the SysInternals Suite.

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

You can then filter the results appropriately to show just the process you are interested in.